# Xcode 9 simulators does not run

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9, simulator

I'm getting error while running an application on simulator using Xcode 9.2. Can not run project on simulator devices.

**Error:**

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

And in my CoreSimulator.log file I have seen:

> Spawning processes in an unbooted state without setting kSimDeviceSpawnStandalone is deprecated.

I tried to remove derived data, quit Xcode and reopen does not solve my issue. Could you please help to solve this bad situation?

*My mac OS version: 10.13.2(High Sierra)
Xcode version: 9.2*

Comment: Can you run this project on real device?

Comment: @ShineMan Yes can run on real device but not on iOS simulators.

Comment: Did you try to change the os version of Simulator?

Comment: @ShineMan Yes i tried to run different version of simulator but result is same.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution;

In my **target** -> **build phases** -> **link binary with libraries** section

> lib386.a

multiplexed. Because of my third party's "xxx.a" library which contains "lib386.a".

Deleted "lib386.a" in link binary section and then simulator runs.

Thanks all.